# Angular Universal Render to Wait for Http Result Observable Subscriber

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, rxjs

I have an Angular Universal app that calls an ASP.Net Web API service.

I have put Console writes on the Angular call to the web service (which was initiated from either a component's constructor or ngOnInit, I tried both) and the subscriber function in Typescript, as well as on the Web API method.

When running the app, I notice that the Angular Universal app does not wait for the Web API's result.

The last console write message that I get is from the Web API, not from the function in the subscriber call.

How can I force the Angular Universal app to wait for the result before finishing the render?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the Angular `HttpClient`, the server-side-render should wait for it to finish before serving your response.

If this doesn't work for you, try subscribing to the call using the `| async` pipe in your template code.

For example:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  public response$ = this.httpClient.get<string>('https://my.api');

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
}
```

```html
<span> {{ response$ | async }} </span>
```